# How to create view based on MvxViewModelRequest for UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, mvvmcross

I am using:

- C#
- MvvmCroos.Core 5.6.3.
- MvvmCroos.Platform 5.6.3.
- Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform 5.2.2
- VS 2015
- Windows 10 target version: Build 14393

  For Wpf approach MvvmCross supports CreateView behavior which based on MvxViewModelRequest returns a view as a FrameworkElement type.

Example:

```
var request = new MvxViewModelRequest(viewModelType, parameterBundle, presentationBundle, null);

var view = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxSimpleWpfViewLoader>().CreateView(request);
```

Unfortunately, `CreateView` and `IMvxSimpleWpfViewLoader` equivalents don't exist in UWP land. How do I achieve same functionality? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In UWP a views is a `Page`. Pages are usually not created directly (although it is still possible), but rather displayed in the context of a `Frame`, which acts as a container and keeps track of navigation stack and navigation parameters for each page. With the container the `Page` also gets notified when it is navigated to and from using `NavigatedTo` and `NavigatedFrom` events.

If you check out the [`MvxWindowsViewPresenter` code](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/be4dfea1099a053d0ad850c8b82767624784ca1d/MvvmCross/Platforms/Uap/Presenters/MvxWindowsViewPresenter.cs), you can see how navigation is handled in UWP. Instead of creating an instance of the page we use `Frame.Navigate` and pass in the type of the page that we want to navigate to and the `Frame` takes care of the lifetime of the page including its instantiation.

Comment: I'll have a look at that. Thanks.